# How to get Data form List<Object> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I Have a main class with the event data which stores the `List<EventDates>, List<MonthStartEnd>, List<WeekStartEnd>`

[image: EventsClass Image]

[image: MonthClass Image]

When the database is created the tables are created separately for each list. The Database Looks Likes this after creation:

[image: Database Looks Likes this]

When I try to get the data from the events table for a specific month range I get the following error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'EventManageWPF.Model.WeekStartEnd get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I use the following to retrieve the data

```
this.db.Events.Where(events => events.weekStartEnd.Any(l => l.weekStart.Equals(weekStartEnds[0].weekStart))).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do i get the data from the month ranges?

The data stored in the database looks as follows

[image: Events Table]

[image: MonthStartEnd Table]

I'm kinda new to c# and entity framework so any help would be great!

Comment: You should share the definition of your entities and a bit more context around the query which is failing.

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post code as text.

Comment: Sorry about that. I refrained from pasting code as this is for a coursework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you that you cannot treat a table like an array. Looks like `weekStartEnds` is a local variable? I would introduce another local variable and assign it the value of `weekStartEnds[0].weekStart` so that EF translator does not see the indexing operation and fails in trying to translate it to SQL.

```
var weekStart = weekStartEnds[0].weekStart;

this.db.Events.Where(events => events.weekStartEnd.Any(l => l.weekStart.Equals(weekStart))).FirstOrDefault();
```